# SwiftUI - Handling redirect URL with SpotifyAPI and AuthorizationCodeFlowPKCEManager

Tags: swiftui, authorization, pkce

I am trying to build a SwiftUI app that uses the SpotifyAPI library (https://github.com/Peter-Schorn/SpotifyAPI) to interact with the Spotify API. I have successfully installed the library and imported it into my project. My app is using the Authorization Code Flow with Proof Key for Code Exchange (PKCE) to handle user authentication. However, I am having trouble handling the redirect URL after authorization.

Here's the code snippet of my SpotifyApp:

```
import SwiftUI
import SpotifyWebAPI

@main
struct SpotifyApp: App {
    @StateObject private var spotify = SpotifyAPI(authorizationManager: AuthorizationCodeFlowPKCEManager(clientId: "clientId"))

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .environmentObject(spotify)
        }
        .onOpenURL { url in
            spotify.authorizationManager.handleURL(url)
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to handle the redirect URL using the .onOpenURL modifier within the WindowGroup to call the handleURL(url) function of the AuthorizationCodeFlowPKCEManager. I expected this to properly handle the URL and continue with the authentication process. However, I am getting the following error:

```
Value of type 'AuthorizationCodeFlowPKCEManager' has no member 'handleURL'
```

I have tried various alternative methods to access the handleURL function but without success. Any suggestions on how to correctly handle the redirect URL using the SpotifyAPI library and AuthorizationCodeFlowPKCEManager in a SwiftUI app?

Comment: You need to implement handleUrl() yourself as shown in the example app: https://github.com/Peter-Schorn/SpotifyAPIExampleApp